# Is there a way to configure RabbitMq to not close connections after missed heartbeats?

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

Is there a way to configure RabbitMq to not close connections after missed heartbeats at all?

Comment: No, but you can disable heartbeats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No, but you can disable heartbeats

eandersson is right, no you can't do that. but disabling heartbeats is probably the wrong idea, too.

the point of a heartbeat is to tell you when your connection to the server drops, so you can take action as soon as possible.

common actions include (but are not limited to):

- crash the app and restart, recreating the needed connection(s)
- re-create the connection(s) without restarting

how you handle the missed heartbear / dropped connection is up to you, but ultimately, the missed heartbeat is a sign that your connection is already dropped, not a cause of dropped connections.